# passing an array of names to _.bindAll - Arguments list has wrong type

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

We use a common pattern in Backbone Views. We have event objects that look like so:

```
var TokenInputBaseView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    'click .remove-token' : 'click_removeToken',
    'mousedown .add-token': 'click_addToken',
    'keydown input'       : 'keydown_input',
    'click input'         : 'click_input',
    'focus .token-input'  : 'focus_input',
    'blur .token-input'   : 'blur_input',
  },
```

In nearly every case we want all the event handlers bound to the View, rather than to their event object. So we do this:

```
initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this, 'click_removeToken', ...);
}
```

We have to manually list every event name. It would be ideal if we could simply pass in an array, but underscore does not enable this use:

```
_.bindAll(this, _.values(this.events));
```

Underscore wants the individual names to be passed in as arguments rather than an array. However, this also does not work:

```
_.bindAll.apply(this, _.values(this.events).unshift(this));
```

Javascript gives this error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type"
```

Any ideas on a good way to simplify the use of bindAll so that it does not require manually listing all the function names to bind?

Comment: There's no need to do that. Backbone will automagically assign the context of the instance for method invoked from the `events` hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing bindAll the return of [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), which is the length of the modified array. You need to either store an array reference, modify it, and then pass that reference to `apply` or employ some other trickery:

```
// note, no need to bind to `this`
_.bindAll.apply(null, [this].concat(_.values(this.events)));
```

A short example:

```js
var target = document.querySelector('#target');

var map = {
  'foo': 'foo',
  'bar': 'bar'
};

function C() {
  this.value = 'Value';
  _.bindAll.apply(null, [this].concat(_.values(map)));
}

C.prototype.foo = function() {
  console.log('hello', this);
  target.textContent = this.value + ' set by foo';
}

C.prototype.bar = function() {
  return this.value;
}

var c = new C();

document.addEventListener('click', c.foo);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>

<div id="target">Click me</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't the context still be `_`?

Comment: @Mathletics No, `bindAll` doesn't actually use any reference to `this` it's a pure function.

Comment: If you want it to behave exactly as calling `_.bindAll()` you should set `_` as the context. Future versions may need it.